# Creating nodes from json including image field upload

Tags: 7, media, nodes

I am trying to create a node programmatically from the data(JSON) sent by my front-end template.

```
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" >
<input id="body" name="body" type="text">
<input type="file" name="pic" id ="pic1" accept="image/*">
```

^^ This is my front end html

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#save").click(function(){
    //alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
  var postData =  [{
      "content-type" : "article",
      "title": jQuery("#title").val(),
      "body" : jQuery("#body").val(), 
      "pic1" : jQuery("#pic1").val(),
  }];
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "my-module/create-artcle/", //This is the menu hook I created
            data: {'article': postData},
            success:function(data){
            //if(data.status === "success"){
              alert(data);
            //  window.location = "/user";
            //}
          }
    });
  });

});
```

^^^ This is my json.

This data is sent to the hook_menu I created, which triggers a callback function to create the node. here is the code for that.

```
function create_article(){
  global $user;

  if(isset($_POST['article'])) {
      $json = $_POST['article'];
      $decodedData = json_decode($json, true);

      $contentType = $decodedData[0]["content-type"];
      $title = $decodedData[0]["title"];
      $body= $decodedData[0]["body"];
      $image1 = $decodedData[0]["pic1"]; 

       //Create a article
       $node = new stdClass();

       //Set values to fields
       $node->type = $contentType;
       $node->title = $title;
       $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $body;

       node_object_prepare($node);
       $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; 
       $node->uid = $user->uid;
       $node->status = 1; 

       $node = node_submit($node); 
       node_save($node);
  }
}
```

So far I am getting my code to work except saving the image, because I'm seriously confused in saving an image to my node.
The value that I get from front-end is simply the name of the image.
my question is :
can I save an image to the node I am creating with what I am getting from front-end ? If so I am confused with this reference https://www.drupal.org/node/201594

could any one guide me to extend this code to save my image..
$image1 this variable contains the image name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is through [Services module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services)

In your case you have to post the image itself and use the file data in node object as a value for the field see that snippet:

```
  //$file_array is the result from saving the file
  //assuming you have the field name is image
  $file_array = api_save_file($_POST['image'], $title);
  $node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = $file_array
```

Note that you have to save the image base64 encoded like

```
//save base64 images as files 
//@return object file object

 function api_save_file($file, $name, $entity_type = 'node', $entity_id = 0){
$data = base64_decode($file);    

$finfo = finfo_open();
$mime_type = finfo_buffer($finfo, $data, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
finfo_close($finfo);
// get file type png. jpg
$ext = $mime_type ? str_replace('image/', '', $mime_type) : 'png';
$file_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $name);

$file = file_save_data($data, 'public://'.$entity.'/'.$file_name.'.'.$ext, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
file_usage_add($file, 'file', $entity_type, $entity_id);

return array(
    'fid' => $file->fid,
    'width' => 800,
    'height' => 600,
    'display' => 1,
    'alt' => $name,
    'title' => $name
);
```

}

Comment: Hi! I will try this out and vote your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to remove all file usage records with id = 0